# CloudControl Kohana Framework detected and push fails.

Tags: kohana, buildpack, cloudcontrol

When deploying my application to CloudControl I suddenly get an unexpected error while pushing the code.

```
remote: [1G-----> Kohana Framework detected        
remote: mkdir: cannot create directory `application/cache': No such file or directory        
remote: [1G !     cloudControl push rejected, failed to compile php app
```

I do not use the typical folder structure of Kohana. I place the system and module folder outside of my application folders. This allows me to keep the application clean and works fine in Kohana.

For example:

```
-doc_root
-- modules (all modules)
-- system (kohana framework only)
-- app1 (some single application)
--- application
---- classes... (and so on)
--- webroot
---- index.php
```

Because I am aware of a LoadBalances document root system I do not have any tmp or cache folders inside of my doc_root.
This error seems to be new and makes it kinda impossible for me right now to push and deploy any changes to my application.

Do I really need to change my folder layout? Can the Buildpack (https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php) detect my structure somehow? Can I tell the Buildpack what my structure looks like?

Comment: That your app was was detected as Kohana is actually a [bug](https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php/issues/7) because the current implementation doesn't allow this layout. As soon as we've fixed the detection, pushing should work.

Comment: Pushing should now be possible and your app should be detected as plain PHP. See my answer below for manual config of the document root.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working again. Maybe someday I will be using the advantage of the new features of buildpack. But right now I stick with my current layout and be just "plain PHP".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This layout is currently not supported by the buildpack. You can [set your document root manually](https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php/blob/master/README.md#manually-setting-the-documentroot) though (in this example AFAICT the webroot would be `/app/www/app1/webroot`).

Comment: What is the difference between "code" and "www" in the deployment?